# Python creates locked files on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I just ran into a problem, which is probably easy to fix - well, for you guys.
I try to create a directory, change to it, create a file in that directory and appened to that file. Everything works fine - except it marks the directory/file as locked and that isn't very convenient for me.
I am running my script as root, because I need to. When I run it normally that problem doesn't occur. I am on Ubuntu and down below is some example code plus a picture of the permissions of the given file, thanks!

```
import os

os.makedirs("foo", exist_ok = True)
os.chdir("foo")

with open("oof", "a") as f:
    f.write("something" + "\n")
```

[image: A picture of the permissions of the given file]

Comment: @Leo Yes, I forgot to mention that, sorry. I need to though - I'm coding a packet analyzer.

Comment: See [os.seteuid()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.seteuid).

Comment: See also [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Don't run things as root, or if you do, reduce your privilege (via seteuid) for every bit except for the one that actually needs it. This is a system thing, not particular to Python or Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you run the script as root so other users can not access this file.
You can change directory permissions:

```
from subprocess import call

call(['chmod', 'mode', 'path'])
```